# How to install joy package

Tags: ros, drone, joy, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS, forgive me if the question relates to fundamental knowledge I am not aware.

What I am trying to do is using joy stick to control A.R. drone 2.0 by ROS in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I am following the instruction here:
http://robohub.org/up-and-flying-with-the-ar-drone-and-ros-getting-started/

```
$ sudo rosdep init
$ rosdep update
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-joystick-drivers
$ rosdep install joy
```

I got stuck at $ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-joystick-drivers. it gives error:
`E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-joystick-drivers`

Since I installed ROS indigo, so I changed it to $ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-joystick-drivers, it runs ok. However it stuck at the next command: $ rosdep install joy, it gives error:

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource joy
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/jade/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/jade/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/jade/stacksenter code here
```

I runs:

```
     $rospack find joy
     [rospack] Error: package 'joy' not found
```

Somehow 'joy' package is not installed. How can I install joy package?

Thanks,
Haifei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217928/how-to-install-joy-package/) by [Haifei](https://answers.ros.org/users/23965/haifei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately this robohub article is quite outdated. ROS *Fuerte* (and two next versions after it: *Groovy* and *Hydro*) are all end-of-lifed. It is also not possible to install ROS *Fuerte* on *Ubuntu* 14.04 AFIK. One of my colleagues is working on shipping a sample joystick teleop launch file with `ardrone_autonomy`. I will update this answer when those changes are tested and merged. The code form the robohub article uses `rosbuild` (the legacy ROS buildtool) <s>which is not supported in ROS *Indigo*</s> (Please check the comment by @gvdhoorn) . In order to use that code, someone needs to convert the build system to `catkin`.

To install joystick drivers and joy package on ROS *Indigo* you can run `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-joy ros-indigo-joystick-drivers` in command line.

PS. Please check [this documentation](http://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) for installation instructions of `ardrone_autonomy` on ROS Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2015-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-21**:
Just to clarify: you can still use rosbuild under Indigo (and even Jade). It's just that there are some restrictions when interacting with catkin workspaces, and you cannot release rosbuild packages anymore.

**Comment by [Haifei](https://answers.ros.org/users/23965/haifei/) on 2015-09-21**:
Thank you for the response.